Set fixed g_ether mac address at firstboot
I would like to have g_ether have a fixed mac, which can be done by the following command:
echo 'options g_ether host_addr='$(dmesg | awk '/: HOST MAC/{print $NF}')' dev_addr='$(dmesg | awk '/: MAC/{print $NF}') | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/g_ether.conf
Now I would like this to be done at first boot, so I added in this specific command in /usr/lib/raspberrypi-sys-mods/firstboot, but somehow and I am quite new to bash, this does not seem to work. It either gets skipped or something, but the file wasn't created when the device is up and running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am using a RPi zero 2 W with 64bit raspios.

That's why I said 02, a zero 2. But thank you for commenting.
